# Elemento inline-block cai ao ser preenchido

Tags: posicionamento, css

Tenho 3 elementos `inline-block`. São 3 quadrados alinhados, resumindo.

Então quando coloco um `div` "filha" em um deles, ele cai e os outros vazios se mantem na posição. Acontece o mesmo com todos.

Mas se eu coloco uma `div` filha dentro(preencha) de TODOS, eles se mantem na posição correta. Do contrário, eles caem.

Vejam com as 3 divs contendo `<figure>` e `<p>`, tudo se alinha.

```css
.blocoexp{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid black;
 }
 
 .blocoexp figure{
  width:30%;
  height:80px;
  border:1px solid black;
 }
 .blocoexp p{
  width:30%;
  height:80px;
  border:1px solid black;
        word-break:break-all;
 }
```

```html
        <div class="blocoexp">
         <figure></figure>
            <p>asdasdasd</p>
        </div>
        <div class="blocoexp">
            <figure></figure>
            <p>asdasdasd</p>
        </div>
        <div class="blocoexp">
         <figure></figure>
            <p>asdasdasd</p>
        </div>
```

Agora vejam se eu retirar o conteudo de uma das divs.

```css
    .blocoexp{
      display:inline-block;
      width:100px;
      height:300px;
      border:1px solid black;
     }
     
     .blocoexp figure{
      width:30%;
      height:80px;
      border:1px solid black;
     }
     .blocoexp p{
      width:30%;
      height:80px;
      border:1px solid black;
            word-break:break-all;
     }
```

```html
    <div id="blocoexpai">
        <div class="blocoexp">
         <figure></figure>
            <p>asdasdasd</p>
        </div>
        <div class="blocoexp">
            <figure></figure>
            <p>asdasdasd</p>
        </div>
        <div class="blocoexp">

        </div>
    </div>
```

Tcharam! Só fica a vazia, as outras caem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema ocorre pois o navegador está alinhando as `DIV`'s `inline-block` pela linha de base do texto contido nelas.

Há duas soluções que eu consigo pensar agora:

- adicionar **`vertical-align: bottom;`** na classe `blocoexp`

  Isso faz com que o navegador alinhe as DIV's verticalmente usando a parte inferior do elemento (`bottom`) e não a linha de base do texto.

  ```css
  .blocoexp {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align: bottom;
  }
  .blocoexp figure {
    width: 30%;
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .blocoexp p {
    width: 30%;
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    word-break: break-all;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div id="blocoexpai">
    <div class="blocoexp">
      <figure></figure>
      <p>asdasdasd</p>
    </div>
    <div class="blocoexp">
      <figure></figure>
      <p>asdasdasd</p>
    </div>
    <div class="blocoexp">
    </div>
  </div>
  ```
- adicionar **`overflow: hidden;`** na classe `blocoexp`

  Isso faz com que o navegador veja o elemento como uma janela, na qual os sub-elementos estão do outro lado da mesma... cortando os elementos que extravasam os limites do elemento pai, e também criando uma espécie de isolamento entre o que há fora e dentro do elemento.

  ```css
  .blocoexp {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .blocoexp figure {
    width: 30%;
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .blocoexp p {
    width: 30%;
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    word-break: break-all;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div id="blocoexpai">
    <div class="blocoexp">
      <figure></figure>
      <p>asdasdasd</p>
    </div>
    <div class="blocoexp">
      <figure></figure>
      <p>asdasdasd</p>
    </div>
    <div class="blocoexp">
    </div>
  </div>
  ```

### Explicação do `vertical-align`

Imagine os elementos PAI e FILHO. Para cada elemento, o navegador possui várias linhas para fazer alinhamento vertical:

- linhas de base e de topo do texto
- linhas inferior, média e superior do elemento
- linhas de texto subscrito e sobrescrito

Quando você indica um `vertical-align` no FILHO, o navegador vai alinhar uma das linhas do FILHO com uma das linhas do PAI, seguindo uma regra para cada valor de `vertical-align` (CSS é assim, você tem que decorar várias regras):

- **`baseline`** => alinha a linha de base do filho com a do pai
- **`bottom`** => alinha a linha inferior do elemento filho com a do pai
- **`middle`** => alinha a linha média do elemento filho com a do pai
- **`top`** => alinha a linha superior do elemento filho com a do pai
- **`sub`** => alinha a linha de base do filho com a linha de texto subscrito do pai
- **`super`** => alinha a linha de base do filho com a linha de texto sobrescrito do pai
- **`text-bottom`** => alinha a linha inferior do elemento filho com a linha inferior do texto do pai (no meu teste, é a linha de texto subscrito do pai, mas acho que na verdade equivale à linha que passa pelo limite inferior de letras como 'j', 'p', 'q' e 'g')
- **`text-top`** => alinha a linha superior do elemento filho com a linha de topo do texto do pai

  - NOTA: no Chrome, observei que a linha de base de um elemento sem texto, é igual a linha inferior do elemento, o que afeta as regras `baseline`, `sub` e `super`.

**Visualização das regras aplicadas lado a lado**

[image: Guias de alinhamento]

```css
.filho {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0;
}
#pai {
  font-size: 48px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="pai">
  I
  <div class="filho" style="vertical-align: bottom;">
    bottom
  </div>
  <div class="filho" style="vertical-align: bottom;"></div>
  I
  <div class="filho" style="vertical-align: middle;">
    middle
  </div>
  <div class="filho" style="vertical-align: middle;"></div>
  I
  <div class="filho" style="vertical-align: top;">
    top
  </div>
  <div class="filho" style="vertical-align: top;"></div>
  I
  <div class="filho" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
    baseline
  </div>
  <div class="filho" style="vertical-align: baseline;"></div>
  I
  <div class="filho" style="vertical-align: text-bottom;">
    text-bottom
  </div>
  <div class="filho" style="vertical-align: text-bottom;"></div>
  I
  <div class="filho" style="vertical-align: text-top;">
    text-top
  </div>
  <div class="filho" style="vertical-align: text-top;"></div>
  I
  <div class="filho" style="vertical-align: sub;">
    sub
  </div>
  <div class="filho" style="vertical-align: sub;"></div>
  I
  <div class="filho" style="vertical-align: super;">
    super
  </div>
  <div class="filho" style="vertical-align: super;"></div>
  I
</div>
```

Comment: Apesar da sua resposta ter resolvido meu problema, eu não entendi a lógica da coisa de fato. Navegador lendo na base do texto?

Comment: Coloquei uma explicação melhorada sobre o `vertical-align`. Me diz sua opinião... se ficou fácil de entender agora, ou se ainda pode ser melhorado.

Comment: Ando meio sem tempo, tô lendo sua resposta aos pedaços e tô conseguindo entender. O que tá me parecendo até agora que é essa propriedade é a mais complicada de todo o CSS.

Comment: por que é que o inline-block vazio tambem n se alinhou na baseline? Aliás, eu acho que se alinhou né? Mas as diz que continham texto respeitaram a partir do texto. Mas porque não a apartir do inline-block ja q ele se comprota como texto?

Comment: Eu ainda to com muita dificuldade mano. Tem como você me aceitar no face?

Comment: A baseline do `inline-block` vazio passa a ser igual ao `bottom` do elemento, já que ele não apresenta nenhum conteúdo.

Comment: Eu só nao consigo entender o comportamento de um inline-block com texto. Não entendo se é porque a linha respeita o texto contido no inline-block e não mais ele em si ou se é outra coisa.

Comment: É exatamente isso que você disse. Você entendeu. Quanto há texto dentro do `inline-block` a baseline é a base do texto contido neste (e não mais o elemento como um todo). Só reforçando o que você disse.

Comment: ainda tô aguardando sua resposta.

Comment: Po nem tinha visto. Eu uso principalmente o SOpt para esclarecer dúvidas, o face não é bom para isso... aliás eu raramente o uso.